# Factoring out common constants in pattern synonym code?

Tags: haskell, pattern-synonyms, overloaded-strings

I had some code like this:

```
newtype T = T Text

pattern Alice = T "Alice"
```

This is fine, but I was using "Alice" in other places. So I decided to factor it out like so:

```
alice :: Text
alice = "Alice"

pattern Alice = T alice
```

But when I built this with warnings on, I got a warning about an unused variable.

I then realised that:

```
pattern Alice = T alice
```

actually matches everything, as opposed just `T "Alice"`

It then seemed weird that even `T "Alice"` was allowed, as `"Alice"` is `Text`, something which is computed.

But then I saw on the [Overloaded Strings](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/overloaded_strings.html) docs that:

> String literals behave very much like integer literals, i.e., they can be used in both expressions and patterns. If used in a pattern the literal will be replaced by an equality test, in the same way as an integer literal is.

So this raises a few questions:

1. Could I even write the pattern `Alice` without enabling the overloaded strings extension?
2. Can I create pattern synonyms where the RHS requires some computation, and have GHC use `Eq` to match, just like it does for numeric and string literals? Or are numeric and string literals a special case and GHC doesn't allow one to generalise that functionality?

Comment: In this context, `"Alice"` is a pattern that matches exactly one string, not that string itself. In the same context, `alice` is a pattern that matches *anything*, not an expression that evaluates to a pattern that matches exactly one thing.

Answer (score 5):

You can use view patterns to perform any computation in the pattern and then use the result to match anything else.

```
ghci> :set -XPatternSynonyms
ghci> :set -XViewPatterns
alice = "Alice"
ghci> pattern Alice <- ((==alice) -> True)
```

Here you apply `(==alice)` to the argument and match the result against `True`.

Answer (score 2):

> Could I even write the pattern Alice without enabling the overloaded strings extension?

**No**, since you need to `OverloadedString`s to also adapt the string literals in *patterns*. If you don't, then it will not work, or at least not without some unpacking. Behind the curtains it will use `fromString` on the value of the pattern and check equivalence, so:

```
f "Alice" = "foo"
f _ = "bar"
```

is essentially equivalent to:

```
f x | x == fromString "Alice" = "foo"
f _ = "bar"
```

As for factoring out subpatterns, why not just make an `AliceText` pattern:

```
pattern AliceText :: Text
pattern AliceText = "Alice"

pattern Alice = T AliceText
```

and thus create different pattern synonyms that can refer to each other. Furthermore a pattern can also be used as *expression* here, so `AliceText` can be used wherever you need `Text` with `"Alice"` as value.

Comment: I think "**No**" is too strong -- after all, you can just write down what the OverloadedStrings extension desugars the pattern to.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a solution I'd recommend, but studying it might be useful to better understand how string/text patterns work.

We can use Template Haskell to generate patterns that correspond to your original string-literal `T "Alice"`, but with a variable string:

```
module StrLitPat where

import Language.Haskell.TH

stringLiteralPattern :: String -> Q Pat
stringLiteralPattern = pure . LitP . StringL

alice :: String
alice = "Alice"
```

This can be spliced into a pattern, including pattern synonym, like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms   #-}

import Data.String (IsString(..))
import Data.Text (Text)

import StrLitPat

newtype T = T Text

pattern Alice = T $(stringLiteralPattern alice)

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ case (T "Alice", T "Bob") of
   (_, Alice) -> "Alice on the right"
   (Alice, _) -> "Alice on the left"
   _          -> "Alice isn't here"
```

Notice how `alice` stands in for a `Text` pattern here, even though its type was declared as `String`! (You could also have made it `IsString s => s`.) This is because Template Haskell uses strings, at compile time, and only in the actual concrete pattern does the `OverloadedStrings` mechanism come into play and allow for the conversion to and from `Text`.